# Sub process output not being returned 'real-time'

Tags: php, symfony

I'm just testing out the Symfony Process Component and it doesn't seem to do what it says on the tin.

Docs state

> When executing a long running command (like rsync-ing files to a remote server), you can give feedback to the end user in real-time by passing an anonymous function to the run() method:

I have 1 file with the following

```
$process = new Process('php terminal.php');
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->run( function ( $type, $buffer ) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
});
```

and another with the following

```
$x = 10;
while( $x ) {
    echo "{$x}\n";
    sleep(1);
    $x--;
}
```

While running this via terminal after a **10 second wait** the output is

```
OUT > 10
OUT > 9
OUT > 8
OUT > 7
OUT > 6
OUT > 5
OUT > 4
OUT > 3
OUT > 2
OUT > 1
```

which shows there are 10 iterations of closure above but there is no output until the process is finished.

Am I missing something here?

Regards, Luke

Comment: I am expecting 10 separate strings of data pushed to the output buffer in real time over a 10 second period, not 1 after 10 seconds

Comment: It actually works for me with your exact code. The doc says: `Support for streaming the output of a process was introduced in Symfony 3.1.`. Do you really have current version?

Comment: just checked: `"name": "symfony/process",  "version": "v3.1.4",  "version_normalized": "3.1.4.0"`

Comment: I tested PHP 5.5 and PHP 7.1 and both work. What version you use and what OS?

Comment: Mac 10.11.6, PHP 5.6.10

Comment: I tested it with PHP 5.6.25 on OSX and it works. I recommend trying it with a different PHP version.

Comment: http://g.recordit.co/OwqfsQ9ntF.gif tried 7, still nothing... hmm

Answer (score 3):

You need to use :

```
flush();
ob_flush();
```

On your first code :

```
$process = new Process('php terminal.php');
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->run( function ( $type, $buffer ) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
    flush();
    ob_flush();
});
```

On the 2nd :

```
$x = 10;
while( $x ) {
    echo "{$x}\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
    $x--;
}
```

More information at php.net : [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-flush.php) and [flush](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.flush.php)